# How to make Server controls in .NET 1.1 render in compliance with Xhtml

Tags: xhtml, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003, legacy-code, html4

I'm "re-skinning" a legacy .NET 1.1 site (i know, don't ask).

Anyway, originally it was all horrible html4.0 markup, and the new design is xhtml.

How do I change the way server controls render in .NET 1.1 amd Visual Studio 2003?

For example, the asp:ImageButton control is rendering without the self closing tag, how do I change this?

cheers!

Comment: Does this blog help? http://weblogs.asp.net/ssivakumar/archive/2004/11/05/252735.aspx

Comment: That would be waste of time, if you have that much time at least I would suggest you to consider upgrading to 2.0 which doesn't require much to do and most likely will work seamlessly. How many server controls you are thinking to change the markup? asp:imagebutton, ..?